# Drupal view compare date

Tags: date, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a data type "v_content" with fields "from" and "untill", both are of type DATE(ISO).

Now I need to configure a view, which will show only those v_contents in date range:
show only if from <= NOW <= untill

Sadly, in Filter criteria in view configuration, I can select the field, but cannot compare the value with current date, there are some predefined other non related settings.
Also in Contextual filters, there is no comparsion settings.

So, how do I filter nodes in view by comparsion of its field values against current date?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure condition for date field you you have select showing default value "select a date" which you can change to "Enter a relative date" and then in input field bellow enter "now".

[image]

Comment: And where exactly this is? In the conditional settings I have this http://screenshot.cz/IW/IWCEQ/d1.png ... in contextual filters, there is more settings, but still nothing like this...

Comment: This would be in the filter criteria section.